# Improve join performance

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 2 tables which i'm required to join.

both have a lot of record.

one of the table(table a) is indexed as follow : account_number,start_date,end_date (all unique) .

the second table is not indexed(table b).

table a have about 450,000,000 records and table b have about 20,000,000 records.
right now the join takes about 20 minutes, I need it faster..
this is the query:

```
select * 
from a, b 
where
   a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND
   TRUNC(a.CREATE_DATE) BETWEEN b.START_DATE AND b.END_DATE
```

Any idea on how to improve it?(indexes ,partitions,another kind of join)
Any thoughts will be welcomed.

Comment: Under most reasonable scenarios, this query is likely to return tens of millions of rows.  How large is the result set?  Your query may already be optimized.  The result set might just be really, really big.

Comment: For beginning you can create index on `b.account_number`. If this column values are dispersed that may be enough.

Comment: Can you post the dbms_xplan output?

Comment: Is the TRUNC function adding functional value here? It's certainly preventing the optimizer from using the available index.

Comment: No matter what kind of optimization is done, keep in mind every row in table A's 450 million rows will have to be evaluated against table B. Is there possibly any filter you could add to table A's rows to reduce the effective work performed by the SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are large tables.  First, write your query using standard `JOIN` syntax:

```
select *
from a join
     b
     on a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = b.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AND
        TRUNC(a.CREATE_DATE) BETWEEN b.START_DATE AND b.END_DATE;
```

Then, I would be inclined to create indexes on `a(ACCOUNT_NUBMER, CREATE_DATE)` and `b(ACCOUNT_NUMBER, START_DATE, END_DATE)`.  Because of the `TRUNC()`, you might want to consider a virtual column that can be used both in the query and in the index.

Your query may be returning so much data that the limiting factor in performance is not the query itself but the result set.  Your two tables are rather large and there is not much filtering in the query.